# GETH accounts imported without my knowledge

Tags: go-ethereum, security, accounts

I expose only port 30303, not 8545. But when I issue commands eth.accounts. I found these accounts were imported without my knowledge:

```
"0xe4fe1fb7e693c529f5a95dd8b1714d1acfdbd058",
"0x0a320acfe5f78d9b689f6dd1fd848ee65a790925",
"0xce3236d5e92d6c5540c51f8378297d4fad4ce6fd",
"0x433ce9234c6cad07244177ddb8fa7614d4626358",
"0x99c979f0302da89025de1e7d812e9d19a4ff9cd3"
```

Is my GETH hacked? Or these are my peers? My GETH is running extremely slow recently and failed to catchup with the sync

Comment: these are not your peers. the command eth.accounts return the list of local account, which should be empty if you never created one. Is your node sync ?

Comment: Yes, my node is synced. But then it was out of synced later, and behaving extremely slowly. That is why I noticed the above changes. May I know how can I remove these accounts from my node? Is it safe to have them there?

Comment: If you didn't create them they shouldn't be here. Can you edit your post with the geth command you're running ? Did you have a previous node installed on your computer ?